# Loop to iterate through API JSON data not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have been stumped on this issue for a couple days, and just want some help getting to the finish line on it.

I have this webapp I'm writing of which an area of it pulls data from the NASA API to display images etc.

Here is the piece of code I'm having trouble with -

```
$http.get("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=" + $scope.yyyy + "-" + $scope.mm + "-" + $scope.dd + "&camera=" + $scope.curCam + "&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $scope.roverdata = response.data
        console.log("this is the mars rover data: " + $scope.roverdata);
        console.log("these are the images: " + $scope.roverdata.photos[0].id);


        console.log("This is the length of the rover photos: " + $scope.roverdata.photos.length);

        //for loopo to push images returned 
        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.roverdata.photos.length; i++) {
            //this isnt working below ---- figure out how to just push the img_src!
            $scope.roverphotos.push($scope.roverdata.photos[i].img_src);
        }
        console.log("These are the pushed rover photos: " + $scope.roverphotos);

        //just testing the image with the first item in the array, maybe use a loop to push all images returned into their own array and display a gallery-
        $scope.test2 = $scope.roverdata.photos[0].img_src;
    }); //end $http.get function(response)
```

In the for loop, if i have the "i" inside the index brackets it says angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot read property 'img_src' of undefined.

If I change the I to one of the index numbers of the photos that it returns it works and can access that index img_src... I dont understand how my loop isn't plugging in each number to push the photos to an array that I can then manipulate as a gallery.  Please help!

Thank you

Comment: I hope that isn't your actual API Key, you really shouldn't be sharing your API key to the public.

Comment: Thanks Richard, crap I totally forgot to remove, I will X out

Answer (score 2):

In the loop condition, `i <= $scope.roverdata.photos.length;` change the comparison operator to simply `<`. It looks like it's failing on the final iteration of the loop -- at that point, it's currently looking for an index that does not exist.

Comment: Wow, that was so simple, love how easy it is to break our code :)  Thanks for the hand!

Answer (score 0):

**try remove "=" of cycle**

```
 $http.get("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=" + $scope.yyyy + "-" + $scope.mm + "-" + $scope.dd + "&camera=" + $scope.curCam + "&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $scope.roverdata = response.data
        console.log("this is the mars rover data: " + $scope.roverdata);
        console.log("these are the images: " + $scope.roverdata.photos[0].id);


    console.log("This is the length of the rover photos: " + $scope.roverdata.photos.length);

    //for loopo to push images returned
    //try remove "=" of cicle 
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.roverdata.photos.length; i++) {
        //this isnt working below ---- figure out how to just push the img_src!
        $scope.roverphotos.push($scope.roverdata.photos[i].img_src);
    }
    console.log("These are the pushed rover photos: " + $scope.roverphotos);

    //just testing the image with the first item in the array, maybe use a loop to push all images returned into their own array and display a gallery-
    $scope.test2 = $scope.roverdata.photos[0].img_src;
}); //end $http.get function(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone will probably have a better answer (I'm pretty green), but I think I've run into this issue and can help a little. First, I'm sure you just left it out of your code (maybe not), but you haven't declared the variable `$scope.roverphotos`, so there isn't anything to push to in your loop. You could try declaring it above the loop.

Also, what are you trying to do with the photos? Are you adding the array you get from the API call to an existing array so that you are continuing to collect them? If so, and you've declared that variable above the code you posted, I'm not sure what's wrong.

Another thing you could try is using map to set the variable with the values you want:

```
$scope.roverphotos = $scope.roverdata.photos.map( function(photo) {
     return photo.img_src
}
```

That'll accomplish the same goal (I think) in a different way. Sometimes I just use map and things seem to work better (Again... I'm new).

Good luck!